# How do I properly send WOL? (Wake-On-Lan)

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

This is my home network:

[image]
The living room repeater is connected to a switch. The switch is connected to the smartTV, the RPi and the media server.

What do I want?
To wake up DESKTOP my media server. The media server (running Win10) is located in the living room, connected to a Fritz Repeater.

What are the steps I've taken so far?
I've enabled WOL on my media server (BIOS settings + LAN adapter configuration + device manager).
I've successfully woken up my media server from shutdown and suspend/sleep modus.
WOL is working in principle but I probably have a routing issue.

When I shutdown my media server I can wake up my media server with my phone or other devices. After 30 minutes sending WOL package my media server is no longer waking up.
However when I send a WOL package through my router's dashboard my media server always wakes up.
This leads me to believe I have a wrong configuration for sending out WOL packages and the package is lost during routing because it forgot where to send the package.

This is the setting I used to send out WOL (client from Google Store: Wake On Lan from Mike Webb):

[image: WOL config]

192.168.178.31 is my media server.
The MAC-address is also set to my media server.

I did change the broadcast address (in picture `Broadcast Adresse`) to 192.168.178.255 it did not work.
I also tried specifying the device ip (in picture `Geräte IP`) to 192.168.178.31 it didn't work either.
Didn't work = sending WOL package after PC has been shutdown/suspended/hibernated for 30 minutes, media server did not turn on.
Immediately sending WOL package after shutting down media server with above configuration worked.

Sending WOL package through router's dashboard media server always wakes up even after PC is shutdown overnight.

So something with my WOL package sending configuration is wrong. Or I have a network issue? Or...? If I should use a different WOL client which one is recommended for my setup? I need a phone and a PC (Win10) WOL client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Broadcast IP Address needs to be set to 192.168.178.255. Else it will certainly not work when the device has been offline for some time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

The x.x.x.255 is typically the broadcast address. When sending a package there it will forward the package to all connected clients.

I managed to now WOL my device even after 24 hour of sleep/suspend/shutdown. However I do not know what I am now doing different that it is working now. I had the Broadcast IP set to 192.168.178.255 and it did not work but now it does.
It might be a user error where I input the wrong IP address or I changed something in the system but I can't tell what it is since I tried a lot.